# Adding new element to many-to-many relation in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, many-to-many

There are two tables:

```
public class Bet{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    ....
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "bets")
    Set<Match> matches = new HashSet<>();
}
```

and

```
@Table(name="event")
public class Match{
    @Id
    private Long id;
    ...

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "bet_event",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "bet_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "event_id") }
    )
    private Set<Bet> bets = new HashSet<>();

    public void addBet(Bet bet) {
        this.bets.add(bet);
        bet.getMatches().add(this);
    }
}
```

Match object is created from API response. It has defined ID field, so it doesn't need to be  generated. I want to write method that would create new Bet, add to it all passed matches and then add this bet object to the set of bets in every single match. At the moment I have something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
public void createBet(List<Match> matches){
        Bet bet = Bet.builder()
                .id(1L)
                .matches(new HashSet<>())
                ...
                .build();

        bet.setMatches(new HashSet<>(matches));
        bet = betRepository.save(bet);

        for(var match : matches) {
            if(matchRepository.existsById(match.getId())){
                var tempMatch = matchRepository.findById(match.getId()).get();
                matchRepository.deleteById(tempMatch.getId());
                tempMatch.addBet(bet);
                matchRepository.save(tempMatch);
            }
            else{
                match.addBet(bet);
                matchRepository.save(match);
            }
        }
    }
```

When I try to add second and more bets I receive error:

`Multiple representations of the same entity [(...).Bet#1] are being merged. Detached: [(...).Bet@16c7455b]; Detached: [(...).Bet@7b76045f]`

How to make it work?